# Python sudoku solver slow

Tags: python, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

So, I created a sudoku solver with BackTracking algorithm. Everything works like a charm, but the solver is really slow compared to and identical solution written in java. Is python really that slow or there is a major bug in my code that I'm missing? 
Here's the code:

```
rida = 0
veerg = 0
maatriks = []
regioon = True
regioonid = []
abimaatriks = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

# Loeb failist maatriksi sisse ja teeb temast listide listi.
def looMaatriks(sisendfail, maatriks):
    fail = open(sisendfail)
    for line in fail:
        line = line.strip()
        if line != "":
            rida = line.split(" ")
            for i in range (0, 9):
                if rida[i] != "-":
                    rida[i] = int(rida[i])
                else:
                    rida[i] = 0
            maatriks.append(rida)
    return maatriks

maatriks = looMaatriks('sisend1.txt', maatriks)

# Loob failist regiooni.
def looRegioon(sisendfail, reg):
    fail = open(sisendfail)
    for line in fail:
        line = line.strip()
        if line != "":
            rida = line.split(" ")
            reg.append(rida)
            for i in range(0,9):
                rida[i] = int(rida[i])
    return reg

regioonid = looRegioon('sisend2.txt', regioonid)
print(regioonid)

# Loob abimaatriksi, kus regioone säilitada.
def looAbiMaatriks(regioon, abimaatriks):
    for i in range (0, 9):
        for j in range (0, 9):
            abi = regioon[i][j]
            abimaatriks[abi-1].append((i, j))            

looAbiMaatriks(regioonid, abimaatriks)
print(abimaatriks)

# Kontrollib, kas antud ruudukeses on number juba või mitte.
def numberOlemas(maatriks, rida, veerg):
    if maatriks[rida][veerg] != 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Kontrollib, kas arv sobib antud ruutu.
def kasSobib(maatriks, rida, veerg, arv):
    for i in range (0, 9):
        if arv == maatriks[rida][i]:
            return False
    for i in range (0, 9):
        if arv == maatriks[i][veerg]:
            return False
    if regioon == False:
        reaalgus = 3*int(rida/3)
        veerualgus = 3*int(veerg/3)
        for k in range(reaalgus, reaalgus + 3):
            for l in range(veerualgus, veerualgus + 3):
                if arv == maatriks[k][l]:
                    return False
    else:
        abi = regioonid[rida][veerg]
        for i in abimaatriks[abi-1]:
            if maatriks[i[0]][i[1]] == arv:
                return False
    return True

# Prindib maatriksi ilusal kujul välja.
def prindiMaatriks(maatriks):
    for i in range (0, 9):
        print(maatriks[i])
    print("")

# Peafunktsioon, mis lahendab kogu maatriksi rekursiivselt.
def lahendaRuut(maatriks, rida, veerg):
    if veerg > 8:
        veerg = 0
        rida += 1
    if rida == 9:
        return True
    if numberOlemas(maatriks, rida, veerg) == True:
        return lahendaRuut(maatriks, rida, veerg+1)
    for i in range(1,10):
        if kasSobib(maatriks, rida, veerg, i):
            maatriks[rida][veerg] = i
            if lahendaRuut(maatriks, rida, veerg+1):
                return True
            else:
                maatriks[rida][veerg] = 0
    return False

print ("Esialgne maatriks:")
prindiMaatriks(maatriks)

print("Lahendatud maatriks:")
lahendaRuut(maatriks, rida, veerg)

prindiMaatriks(maatriks)
```

Here's the input for sisend1.txt:

```
- - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - -
```

Here's the input for sisend2.txt:

```
1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3

1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3

1 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3

1 1 4 5 5 5 5 2 2

4 4 4 4 5 6 6 6 6

7 7 5 5 5 5 6 8 8

9 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 8

9 9 9 7 7 7 8 8 8

9 9 9 9 9 7 8 8 8
```

Input2 contains 3x3 regions for a custom sudoku.
If You want to test without regions, just change regioon = False in the beginning.
Input 1 is just an empty sudoku to be filled.

Comment: I believe this belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is room for improvement using list comprehensions and some built in functions.

For instance instead of:

```
 rida = line.split(" ")
 for i in range (0, 9):
      if rida[i] != "-":
          rida[i] = int(rida[i])
      else:
          rida[i] = 0
```

You can use list comprehensions and do:

```
rida = line.split(" ")
rida = [int(r) if r != "-" else 0 for r in rida]
```

Also eliminate some for loops with built in functions, e.g.

```
for i in range(0,9):
    rida[i] = int(rida[i])
```

Use map:

```
map(int, rida)
```

Also remove unnecessary for loops. Replace:

```
for i in range (0, 9):
    if arv == maatriks[rida][i]:
        return False
for i in range (0, 9):
    if arv == maatriks[i][veerg]:
        return False
```

With:

```
for i in rage(0, 9):
    if arv in [maatriks[rida][i], maatriks[i][veerg]]:
        return False
```